# Após passar uma classe por referencia de interface, como recuperar seu Tipo?

Tags: c#

Se eu receber uma classe por referencia de interface, existe alguma forma de recuperar o tipo original que a implementava?

Dessa forma eu poderia passá-lo em uma sobrecarga de métodos pra cada tipo específico.Ou isso não é adequado/possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível e é bem tranquilo.

Você pode definir se um objeto é de determinado tipo usando os operadores `is` e `as`.

Se você estiver usando versões novas do C# (7 ou superior), pode usar *pattern matching* para resolver este problema.

Por exemplo:

```cs
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Metodo(new Classe1()));
    Console.WriteLine(Metodo(new Classe2()));
}

string Metodo(Interface parametro)
{
    // fazer algo aqui
    
    var retorno = parametro switch
    {
        Classe1 c => MetodoClasse1(c),
        Classe2 c => MetodoClasse2(c),
        _ => throw new Exception("Tipo não tratado")
    };
    
    return retorno;
}

string MetodoClasse1(Classe1 parametro) => parametro.PropriedadeX;
string MetodoClasse2(Classe2 parametro) => parametro.PropriedadeY;

interface Interface { }

class Classe1 : Interface 
{ 
    public string PropriedadeX => "Classe 1";
}

class Classe2 : Interface
{
    public string PropriedadeY => "Classe 2";
}
```

Comment: Eu preciso dar uma saída, mas já edito com mais detalhes sobre os operadores `is` e `as`.

Comment: De qualquer maneira, muito obrigado pela resposta!